# Django | CKEditor - Image Upload option not showing in App

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

In admin all CKEditor option is showing and working properly. I can upload image in main admin dashboard. But in App in Image "Uoload" option is not showing. Please see those images than you have a clear view,

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Others option is working properly without image Upload.

settings.py

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'widget_tweaks',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

INSTALLED_APPS += THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

# CkEditor Upload path
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

# CkEditor Custom Configuration
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'width': 680,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(['codesnippet']),
    },
}
```

template.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}>
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**step1:**
goto settings.py and add -> X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

**step2**
goto your forms.py ->
here no need to extra widget.
[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47bMf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with version 6.1.0 of django-ckeditor.
After thinking about it, look in the github code of the project and apparently there is a new field for the forms that solves this problem, at least for me now if it works well for me.

```
from django import forms
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextFormField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingFormField



class CkEditorForm(forms.Form):
    ckeditor_standard_example = RichTextFormField()
    ckeditor_upload_example = RichTextUploadingFormField(
        config_name="my-custom-toolbar"
    )
```

[code oficial repo ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor_demo/demo_application/forms.py)

Answer (score 0):

in admin.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget
from blog.models import Blog

class BlogAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogAdminForm

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```